# How to Bypass Google Recaptcha while scraping with Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Python code to request the URL:

```
agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'} #using agent to solve the blocking issue
response = requests.get('https://www.naukri.com/jobs-in-andhra-pradesh', headers=agent)
#making the request to the link
```

Output when printing the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Naukri reCAPTCHA</title> #the title in the actual title of the URL that I am requested for
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.naukimg.com/s/4/101/c/common_v62.min.css" />      
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>   
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: That's Google Recaptcha, which for preventing web scraping.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using `Google Cache` along with a `referer` (in the header) will help you bypass the captcha.
Things to note:

- Don't send more than 2 requests/sec. You may get blocked.
- The result you receive is a cache. This will not be effective if you are trying to scrape a real-time data.
  Example:

```py
header = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36" ,
    'referer':'https://www.google.com/'
}

r = requests.get("http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.naukri.com/jobs-in-andhra-pradesh",headers=header)
```

This gives:

```py
>>> r.content
[Squeezed 2554 lines]
```

Comment: passing this captcha will it cause any trouble moving ahead?

Comment: @kmonish not unless you avoid the referer and cache while requesting. do requests with a time interval

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese When I try to navigate to next page it is getting back to older link for the next page. Does this not allow us to navigate and scrape?

Comment: @kmonish did you add the webcache.google.... prefix to the url,for navigating?

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese it shows on the search engine that the URL is not found in the server

Comment: @kmonish could you give the url? comment the url here

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese 
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.naukri.com/jobs-in-andhra-pradesh-2

Comment: @kmonish it fails because the site wasnt cached

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese I just realized that some links are not getting cached like how others get. Is there any other way where we can resolve this issue

Comment: I have added all these headers, but it still shows recaptcha sometimes.