# How can I bypass 403 error in python using requests?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, python-requests, http-status-code-403

I know that some of you already wrote about this problem, but after all atempts nothing works for me. So when I try to scrape web page (https://www.askgamblers.com/) I get 403 error. I already tried:

- Changing to difrend request modes (GET, POST, HEAD)
- Different User-Agent (I copy the same User-Agent that i found in dev console in Chrome)
- Putting more params in header (i copy whole header that i found in dev console)
- Using session

And still nothing works for me. What could try next. Did i miss something? What would you do in this case? You can also check my code with only user agent in header.

```py
url = "https://www.askgamblers.com/"
page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'})
print(page.status_code)
```

I am using the latest version of requests libary (2.26.0)

This is my first post, so be gentle on me :)

EDIT:

My problem was solved with this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61379638/17637402

Comment: first display `page.text` to see what you get - maybe it asks you to resolve `Captcha` or to run `JavaScript` - and then you can't resolve it using `requests` but you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`.

Comment: when I display text of web page, it say that i need to solve Captcha. Is this posible to do with python?

Comment: if it would be simple to solve Captcha then Captcha would be useless. Some people try to use Machine Learning for this - but it needs complex method and not always work. There are also portals which can resolve Captcha but you have to pay - they use real people to solve your Captcha :)